# Convert a Bootstrap site to an Orchard module

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7, orchardcms-1.8, orchard-modules

I'm trying to get an executive permission to build our project on top of the Orchard framework, but first I have to show a brief demo on how our current web app can be integrated in Orchard.

Our web app is based on Twitter Bootstrap 2.2 and ASP.NET MVC 4.5, and it is a single page application. So there is only a single `Index.cshtml` view that I need to load. All I'm trying to do for now is to show that view inside an Orchard site.

Reading in the forums it looks like that creating a Module is recommended over creating a Theme for this case. I copied our web project under `Orchard\Modules` and created a `module.txt` file. The module can be enabled from the Admin panel, but I'm pretty much stuck at this point. So what is the next step to show it? Thanks!

Comment: Checkout this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621135/single-page-design-using-orchard-cms

Comment: Reading it and trying to understand. I wished there was a module just for this, that wrapped an HTML or MVC app and displayed it in a widget or page inside Orchard. That could be a great first step for apps that want to integrate in the Orchard framework.

Comment: While searching codeplex it looks like a few other people requested this functionality already 2 years ago, and said they would implement it. I did not find such a module, but maybe you could contact one of them to request their code/module.
I would like to give it a shot, but I don't think this will be in the near future due to little free time.

Comment: Yes, one of the greatest ways to bring new users is to minimize the barrier to entry. If entry for me requires learning some of the unsupported advanced concepts first, then that would be a let-down.